# I need a faster method to recursively find file metadata Tags, my VBA script is too slow

Tags: vba, performance, shell, recursion, metadata

I have built a script in VBA that recursively looks through folders to find the metadata "Tags" on files. It takes over 20 minutes to do a small file structure and I need this to work on a much larger file structure.
Is VBA the wrong tool for the job?

It takes in my list of tags to search for and file directory

Things I've tried to speed it up: 
-Once it finds one match in the keyword list it stops looking through the other keywords

-If there is no keyword it doesn't even bother looking for matches

Here is the subroutine:

```vb
        Sub FolderSearcher(ByVal SourceFolder As String, KeywordList As Variant)
        'A recursive sub that searches metadata Tags for the Keywords and populates the output

        Dim oFSO, oSourceFolder, oSubFolder As Variant 'FSO
        Dim oShell, oDir As Variant 'Shell
        Dim KeywordListSize As Integer
        Dim DirectoryItem As Variant
        Dim vFileName, vFileKeyword As Variant
        Dim k As Integer 'Counter

        'Create FileSystemObject And Shell Application objects
        Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set oSourceFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(SourceFolder)
        Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

        KeywordListSize = UBound(KeywordList) - LBound(KeywordList)

        'Loop through all Sub folders
        For Each oSubFolder In oSourceFolder.SubFolders
            ' Look through all the files in the folder
            Set oDir = oShell.Namespace(oSubFolder.Path)
            For Each DirectoryItem In oDir.Items
                vFileName = oDir.GetDetailsOf(DirectoryItem, 0) 'Detail 0 is the file name
                If Right(vFileName, 4) = ".pdf" Then 'check if it's a PDF
                    vFileKeyword = PDFkeyword(oSubFolder.Path, vFileName) 'PDFs work a little differently
                Else
                    vFileKeyword = oDir.GetDetailsOf(DirectoryItem, 18) 'Detail 18 is the file tag
                End If

                If vFileKeyword = "" Then
                    GoTo NextDirItem
                End If

                ' Loop through all the searchlist keywords to check for a match
                For k = 0 To KeywordListSize
                    If vFileKeyword = KeywordList(k) Then
                        Call OutputSubroutine(oSubFolder.Path, vFileName, k)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next k

                NextDirItem:
            Next DirectoryItem

            'Recursive search through all the subfolders
            Call FolderSearcher(oSubFolder.Path, KeywordList)
        Next oSubFolder


        'Release Objects
        Set oSubFolder = Nothing
        Set oSourceFolder = Nothing
        Set oFSO = Nothing
        Set oDir = Nothing
        Set oShell = Nothing

    End Sub
```

The inputs:
KeywordList is a 1D array of variable length that holds strings.

SourceFolder is a string that contains my file path i.e. \files\example

I took a look at [Optimize Speed of Recursive File Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511217/optimize-speed-of-recursive-file-search-in-subdirectories) but there were no useful answers.

I would appreciate tips on how I can get this to speed up. Or advice on other languages that could perhaps perform this work more efficiently than VBA. Thank you!

edit*
I was asked to add the PDF keyword function

```vb
Public Function PDFkeyword(InFilePath As Variant, InFileName As Variant) As String
    'This function is used to read the metadata from a PDF
    'Inputs: the folder path and file name
    'Output: the PDF keyword

    Dim oFile As String
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strKeywords As String

    Set oApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set oDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    oFile = InFilePath & "\" & InFileName

    'Grab the keywords from the PDF file
    With oDoc
      If .Open(oFile) Then
        'strFileName = .GetFileName    'not needed rn but could be handy
        strKeywords = .GetInfo("Keywords")
        .Close
      End If
    End With

    PDFkeyword = strKeywords

    'Release Objects
    Set oDoc = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing

End Function
```

The small file structure only had like 3 folder levels and 16 files. The large structure probably has 5+ folder levels and ~1000 files.

Comment: How large is a "small file structure" - how many files/folders approximately ?  Have you tried commenting parts of your code out and comparing run times?  How many PDF's vs. other file types?  Can you show the code for `PDFkeyword` ?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I added additional information to the post. I compared the run length of all my subs and this was the longest, I have not timed the individual parts of this sub. Would you recommend just timing each of the loops?

Comment: See my code below - that was pretty fast in my testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a slight re-write to remove the recursion, and changing your PDF function to use Static variables for the Acrobat objects.

On my machine it processed 3182 files in about 4.5 sec.

```vb
Sub FolderSearcher(ByVal SourceFolder As String, KeywordList As Variant)

    Dim oFSO, oSourceFolder, oSubFolder As Variant
    Dim oShell, oDir As Variant 'Shell
    Dim KeywordListSize As Long
    Dim DirectoryItem As Variant
    Dim vFileName, vFileKeyword As Variant
    Dim k As Long 'Counter
    Dim colFolders As New Collection
    Dim fldr, subFldr, fCount As Long

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oSourceFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(SourceFolder)
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    KeywordListSize = UBound(KeywordList) - LBound(KeywordList)

    colFolders.Add oSourceFolder  '<<< first folder for processing

    Do While colFolders.Count > 0

        Set fldr = colFolders(1)  'get the first folder to process
        colFolders.Remove 1       '...then remove from the collection

        For Each subFldr In fldr.subfolders 'capture subfolders for processing
            colFolders.Add subFldr
        Next subFldr

        Set oDir = oShell.Namespace(fldr.Path)
        For Each DirectoryItem In oDir.Items
            fCount = fCount + 1
            vFileName = oDir.GetDetailsOf(DirectoryItem, 0)
            If LCase(Right(vFileName, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
                vFileKeyword = PDFkeyword(fldr.Path, vFileName) 'PDFs work a little differently
            Else
                vFileKeyword = oDir.GetDetailsOf(DirectoryItem, 18) 'Detail 18 is the file tag
            End If

            If Len(vFileKeyword) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Got keyword:" & vFileKeyword
                For k = 0 To KeywordListSize
                    If vFileKeyword = KeywordList(k) Then
                        'Call OutputSubroutine(oSubFolder.Path, vFileName, k)
                        Debug.Print fldr.Path, vFileName, k
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next k
            End If
        Next DirectoryItem
    Loop
    Debug.Print "Processed " & fCount & " files"
End Sub

Public Function PDFkeyword(InFilePath As Variant, InFileName As Variant) As String
    Dim oFile As String
    Static oApp As Object
    Static oDoc As Object
    Dim strFileName As String, strKeywords As String
    'only create objects once...
    If oApp Is Nothing Then Set oApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    If oDoc Is Nothing Then Set oDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

    oFile = InFilePath & "\" & InFileName
    With oDoc
      If .Open(oFile) Then
        strKeywords = .GetInfo("Keywords")
        .Close
      End If
    End With
    PDFkeyword = strKeywords
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, this sped it up significantly! It was able to process 20905 files in under 2 minutes.